# SSIS Use with SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis

We have a full SQL Server license, and are planning on setting up a SQL Server Express to house a different set of data.

Is it possible to install SSIS using the full SQL Server License and then to migrate data into a SQL Server Express?

Additional Details:

- Our SQL Server Express will house data for ArcGIS Server Workgroup (which is limited to using SQL Server Express)
- The data will be coming out of a PostgreSQL database and being migrated to the SQL Server Express
- The data is completely tabular, no geometry will be migrated via this method

Cheers.

Comment: I know of no reason why it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Is this a one-time activity or an ongoing process?

Comment: @billinkc Its just a one time activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You'll be connecting to the SQL Server Express instance as a data source and therefore will be able to interact with it in the same way as a non-express instance of SQL Server.

As it is a data source, SSIS does not *care* whether it's getting the data from a paid for / free version of SQL Server / any other RDBMS.

Comment: Is there a long answer, like will the SSIS need to be installed on the same machine as the SQL Server? Just trying to get an idea of the requirements.

Comment: No,  no long answer I'm afraid. You'll be pleased to know it's that simple (no joke!), SSIS installed as part of a full SQL Server licence has the ability to interact with a SQL Server Express edition licence in exactly the same way it would with a paid for licence.

Comment: Okay thanks! Follow up question. You said its installed as part of a full SQL Server, is it possible to install it on a desktop pc, while SQL Server is installed on a server somewhere else?

Comment: @roemhildtg Yes, you can install SSDT (the tools which include SSIS) on any development machine. Don't even need SQL Server for it.

Comment: @KyleHale Okay great. Thanks so much